# Store a randomly generated integer as a variable in c++

Tags: c++, random

I am working with the pseudo random function `srand()` to generate a number between a range of two integers (1 and 4).

I include `ctime` and use a flag controlled while loop to check to see that the numbers will be different each loop.

```
time_t t;
time(&t);
srand(t);
```

and then print out the results

```
cout << "My random number" << (rand()%(1-5))+1 << endl;
```

I wish to replace `(rand()%(1-5))+1` with a variable ex : `int myRandomNumber` for use in another loop for determining how many objects will be generated later on in my code

How can i assign the desired random value i get to `myRandomNumber`?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: It works fine if you just do `cout << (rand()%(1-5))+1` it would just be easier to work with this number generated later if it was just and integer variable.

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Answer (score 4):

```
int myRandomNumber = (rand() % 4) + 1;
```

Comment: If you care about uniformity at that level of detail, you have no business using `rand`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: It's also not, in general, 7.

Comment: @GregS - The IEEE certified random number is 4.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the variable:

```
int myRandomNumber;
```

and then assign the value to the variable:

```
myRandomNumber=(rand()%(1-5))+1;
```